# How to retrieve the values from list using indexes by linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of int that contains 5,6,7,8,5,4,3. I like to retrieve the value from list using their index. For example, I give start index as 1 and end index 4 I will get 6,7,8,5 in new list. How can I do this in Linq?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx):

```
var results = list.Skip(1).Take(4);
```

EDIT: Note that it's not clear from your question exactly what limits you're using. If you're trying to be inclusive on both ends, using 0-based indexing, you want:

```
var results = list.Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex - startIndex + 1);
```

Note that this won't let you get 0 results though - you may want to make `endIndex` *exclusive* so that if it equals `startIndex`, you get nothing. Then the code is:

```
var results = list.Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex - startIndex);
```

Or an alternative approach is to use them the other way round. For example, the last snippet above is equivalent to:

```
var results = list.Take(endIndex).Skip(startIndex);
```

Comment: not that clear if he wanted to change that to select indexes 2 to 4 instead, say. You'd have to pass in list.Skip(2).Take(3) then.

Answer (score 2):

this may work for you:

```
list.Where((l, index) => index >= 1 && index <= 4  )
```

Comment: Note that iterating over that requires the *whole* sequence to be evaluated, even if logically you know you've finished.